# Problem with RFID-RC522 and Raspberry PI Background script

Tags: python, boot, rfid

I am working a project to read an RFID tag, and make the buzzer sound. It works correctly in foreground. I call the python script via /etc/rc.local and it is triggered when I execute /etc/rc.local via ssh session. However, when I reboot my raspberry pi, the RFID reader does not respond. I can see the process via `ps -aef|grep python`. I am following [this tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/).

At `/etc/rc.local` I added this command just right before *exit 0*:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py &
```

To successful test it I log in as user **pi** from ssh and execute:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /etc/rc.local
```

Please help here.

Regards

Comment: What actual command did you add to /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: i am using /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py &

Comment: Redirect any output to a log : /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py >> /home/pi/templog.txt 2>&1 &

Comment: tried it..it is not generating templog.txt

Comment: Do you have any print statements at the start of the code? I assume you put the command before the 'exit 0' line?

Comment: yes..i have done it before exit 0 and i am able to call it successfully when i take ssh session and execute /etc/rc.local but when system call this script at time of reboot then RFID will not work even though i see python process in background..

Comment: I think code execution is not happening due to reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522() line..

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: [Read this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md)

Comment: I put print statement after SimpleMFRC522() and before read() method and redirected output to log file but it is not working.

Comment: Add 'import sys' at the start of your code, then 'sys.stdout.flush()' after every print statement.

Comment: With ssh you are logged in as user **pi**, isn't it? What exactly is the command do you enter on the command line to successfully execute the script?

Comment: @CoderMike after import sys, content is coming in templog file but rfid is still not working..

Comment: @Ingo pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /etc/rc.local

Comment: Remove the try: and finally: from your code - its probably throwing an error which is not being shown as its being handled by the finally.

Comment: Yes..you are right..I think issue was in GPIO.cleanup() and i called it in first line of program and after each GPIO call and it is working now...Thanks a lot for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to capture output from a python script failing at startup:**

**Redirect any output to a log:**

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py >> /home/pi/log.txt 2>&1 &
```

2>&1 redirects standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr)

**Force Pythons buffered output to be flushed:**

Add 'import sys' at the start of your code, then 'sys.stdout.flush()' after every print statement.

```
import sys
print(‘test’)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Remove error handling:**

Remove any try: finally: blocks that may be handling/hiding any errors that may be occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using *Raspbian Stretch*. This comes with *systemd* which emulates  */etc/rc.local*. Because of this emulation it is known that it has problems. Look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). As suggested there you should use *systemd* direct to start services. But first remove the line from `/etc/rc.local`. Then you have to create a unit. Do it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force edit myscript.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable and start your new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --now enable myscript.service
```

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status myscript.service
rpi ~$ journalctl --unit=myscript.service
```